# New serial window in GNU Screen

Tags: gnu-screen, serial-port

I know that I can launch Screen as a serial port terminal from scratch. What I want to do is to create a new window inside an already running screen session as a serial terminal. so that I don't need to create a window and run minicom in it.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> `:screen /dev/ttyS0`

Comment: Doesn't work for some reason. That was what i tried before asking.

Comment: I had to add the baud rate: `:screen /dev/ttyS0 115200`

Answer (score 1):

Type this on a command line within a screen session.

For a built in serial port.

```
screen -X screen /dev/ttyS0
```

For a usb-to-serial port adapter.

```
screen -X screen /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Note: '-X' is a capital X.